# Star Trek: Why Is Voyager Referred To Without A "The" In Front?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager, spaceship

Just happened to catch S1E3 yesterday (Parallax), and noticed that Paris refers to *Voyager* as *the Voyager*. Whenever we hear about other ships in *Star Trek*, they are always prefaced by "the" - "the Enterprise", "the Defiant", even "the Equinox" on *Voyager* as I recall. At some point in *Voyager*, the "the" was dropped - is there a reason why? It sounds awkward to me, but I usually rewatch the last few seasons of *Voyager*, which might bias me. Given that it seems the writers started out with using the definite article and later dropped it, I'm curious if the showrunners ever addressed this, as I'm sure people noticed the shift.

Comment: @Politank-Z Interesting theory in that Q/A, but I suppose I'm hoping for something a little bit more definitive. I have to believe this was asked of the showrunners at some point and they provided an answer, even if it was just "it sounded better."

Comment: If you can find that, it would be an excellent answer for that question.